# wpf MVVM confusion

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have been looking at MVVM for the last couple days and thought i would try out a simple example to update a text box with a time. However i'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this.  I have a two projects in my Solution.. one i'm calling TimeProvider that right now is just returning Datetime event and another that is called E. Eventually i will use TimeProvider to provide a lot more information but i want to understand something simple first.  Can some one please tell me why i'm not geting the gui to update.

```
namespace E.TimeProvider
{
    public interface ITimeSource
    {
        void Subscribe();

        event Action<Time> TimeArrived;
    }
}
namespace E.TimeProvider
{
    public class Time
    {
        private DateTime _earthDate;

        public Time()
        {

        }

        public Time(DateTime earthDate)
        {
            this._earthDate = earthDate;
        }

        public DateTime EarthDate
        {
            get { return _earthDate; }
            set { _earthDate = value; }
        }
    }
}

namespace E.TimeProvider
{
    public class TimeSource : ITimeSource
    {
        private const int TIMER_INTERVAL = 50;

        public event Action<Time> TimeArrived;

        private bool subscribe;

        public TimeSource()
        {
            subscribe = false;
            Thread timeGenerator = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GenerateTimes));
            timeGenerator.IsBackground = true;
            timeGenerator.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            timeGenerator.Start();
        }

        public void Subscribe()
        {
            if (subscribe)
                return;

            subscribe = true;
        }

        private void GenerateTimes()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                GenerateAndPublishTimes();
                Thread.Sleep(TIMER_INTERVAL);
            }
        }

        private void GenerateAndPublishTimes()
        {
            DateTime earthDate = DateTime.Now;
            Time time = new Time(earthDate);
            TimeArrived(time);
        }
    }
}
```

Then i have my project E
xaml

```
<Window x:Class="E.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="200" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Exiled" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <my:TimeControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="timeControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="200" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="E.TimeControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="200" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Height="41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,31,0,0"  Text="{Binding Path=EarthTime}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176" FontSize="35" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the rest

```
namespace E
{
    public class TimeControlViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        private readonly ITimeSource _source;


        public ObservableCollection<TimeViewModel> Times { get; set; }

        public TimeControlViewModel()
        {
            this.Times = new ObservableCollection<TimeViewModel>();
        }

        public TimeControlViewModel(ITimeSource source)
        {
            this.Times = new ObservableCollection<TimeViewModel>();

            _source = source;
            _source.TimeArrived += new Action<Time>(_source_TimeArrived); 
        }

        public void Subscribe()
        {
            _source.Subscribe();
        }

        void _source_TimeArrived(Time time)
        {
            TimeViewModel tvm = new TimeViewModel();
            tvm.Time = time;
        }   
    }
}

namespace E
{
    class SubscribeCommand
    {
        private readonly TimeControlViewModel _vm;

        public SubscribeCommand(TimeControlViewModel vm)
        {
            _vm = vm;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _vm.Subscribe();
        }
    }
}

namespace E
{
    public class TimeViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public TimeViewModel()
        {

        }

        public Time Time
        {
            set
            {
                this.EarthDate = value.EarthDate;
            }
        }

        public DateTime EarthDate
        {
            get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DateProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Date.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EarthDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(TimeViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few issues here:

1. You're not seeing an update, because the `DataContext` of your Window or UserControl is not set to the `TimeViewModel` instance you create.
2. Typically, ViewModel instances should not be DependencyObjects.  Instead, implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  This keeps them from having a dependency on WPF, but still allows them to work properly with MVVM.

I'd recommend reading through a detailed introduction to MVVM, such as the [one I wrote here](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/).  In particular, you'll need to understand how templating works and the `DataContext` in order to use binding properly.

Comment: Thank you sir, I found your series of articles very informative.

Comment: Eh, I don't think ViewModels shouldn't extend DependencyObject.  I do think, however, you should keep them as slim as possible, meaning the stuff you'd want to reuse wouldn't have those dependencies.

Comment: @Will: In what scenario would you see it as appropriate for a ViewModel to extend DependencyObject directly?  There is rarely any reason for this (there are, of course, some useful scenarios - but I'd see it as a very rare exception, not the norm...)

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Rarely?  I disagree.  There are many, starting with KISS, leading to DRY, etc.  I don't buy the purist view of VMs.  Nobody reuses ViewModels in other applications, so why pretend otherwise?

Comment: @Will: Even in the same application, a DO adds a lot of extra overhead, and pulls in some fairly odd usage.  What's the purpose of extending DO in your VM vs using INPC?  I'd agree with KISS - which is why it seems like an edge case to me...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Eh, on the overhead.  Knuth, etc.  DOs are much easier to create and modify than types that extend INPC.  At least, for me.  I've got some superawesome snippets for all my dependency property needs.  Myself, I like being able to treat a VM as a DO, as I already instantiate them in xaml.  As DOs, I can (and have) bound them to each other etc.

Comment: @Will: I wasn't necessarily talking about perf. overhead - but maintainability overhead.  But heh, whatever works - I tend to do VM first instead of View first, in which case, ViewModel as DO seems very odd.

Answer (score 0):

For a start it looks like you're binding to EarthTime:

```
Text="{Binding Path=EarthTime}"
```

but the property itself is called EarthDate

```
public DateTime EarthDate
```